# Creating a new date column based on a condition and an existing date column and time delta column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, conditional-statements

I have a database that looks like -

```
date                  Add
21-Dec-19       1-Month
13-Nov-19      3-Months
```

I want to create a new column, 'New', based on a condition that if the date is less than a specified date, it should add the no of days (in timedelta) implied by the add column.

The code I am using is -

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['add'] = df['add'].mapp({'1-Month': np.timedelta64(30,'D'), '3-Months': np.timedelta64 (90,'D')})
def new(row):
   if df['date'] < pd.to_datetime('12/15/2019'):
      val == df['date'] + df['add']
   else:
      val == df['date']
return val

df.apply(lambda row:new(row), axis=1)
```

I get the following error

> ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? It’s a common problem, there are multiple resources available on the subject.

Comment: What do you think the correct code should be to achieve the desired result?

Comment: is this the result you want: 0   2020-01-20
1   2020-02-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You are defining your function with `row`, yet using `df`. This means that when making the comparison for your `if/else` statement, the function doesn't know how to properly evaluate the condition. Do I return True if all values are less than the one passed? If any value is less? That's why it's returning the ambiguity error.
- When you are defining `val` which you use `return` on, you need to only use one `=` sign, since 2 will compare `val` to a value, and will return an error because `val` has never been defined.
- For this case, when using `apply`, you don't need to use `lambda`, calling the function is enough.

This should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
data = {'date':['21-Dec-19','13-Nov-19'],'add':['1-Month','3-Months']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['add'] = df['add'].map({'1-Month': np.timedelta64(30,'D'), '3-Months': np.timedelta64 (90,'D')})
def new(row):
    if row['date'] < pd.to_datetime('12/15/2019'):
        val = row['date'] + row['add']
    else:
        val = row['date']
    return val

df['new'] = df.apply(new,axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        date     add        new
0 2019-12-21 30 days 2019-12-21
1 2019-11-13 90 days 2020-02-11
```

Comment: I literally use the same code and get that same error still!

Comment: If you are literally copy and pasting my code, you shouldn't. I've just run it again with no issues!